# Sveltekit fetch file from static folder

Tags: javascript, deployment, fetch, server-side-rendering, svelte

In sveltekit i have a static folder, in which i have .zip file,
to get it locally i do something like:

`const res = await fetch("/static/makeup.zip")`

It works fine, but when i deployed my app i've got a 404 error

I've tried putting this file to different directories, tried different urls like: `"/makeup.zip", "./static/makeup.zip", "makeup.zip"`

(i think someone who knows gatsby/nuxt can help)

Where should i put this file or how the query should look like ? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was: create folder named public and put this file into it, the request looks like this : `await fetch("/makeup.zip")`